# reactjs: How to replace the entire route table programmatically

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux, react-router-v4, mobx-react

given the following;

```
let render = () => {
  const routes = require('./routes/index').default(store)

  ReactDOM.render(
    <AppContainer store={store} routes={routes} />,
    MOUNT_NODE
  )
}
// ========================================================
// Go!
// ========================================================
render()
```

which works with the assumption that the entire app is built knowing all the routes and stores.

I would like to rebuild the routes and store programatically after the app is running.

The new routes and stores are coming in as a plugin which I will be bringing in by injecting a plugin bundle.js into the DOM programatically.  So I don't know the routes or stores up front.

I have done this using riotjs where I can swap out the entire route table and add and remove stores dynamically.  I am just now starting to learning react-redux and am hoping for some hints as to where to focus my research.

A more concise example

```
let store = createStore1()
let store2 = createStore2()
let routes = require('./routes/index').default(store)
let routes2 = require('./routes2/index').default(store2)

let render = () => {     
  ReactDOM.render(
    <AppContainer store={store} routes={routes} />,
    MOUNT_NODE
  )
}
// ========================================================
// Go!
// ========================================================
render()
```

I want to programmatically switch over to routes2 and store2 at runtime.

Comment: Can't you use `redux` to `dispatch` the routes into global state each time they need to be changed and then get them from state inside your `AppContainer`?

Comment: @Puratory I think I did what you suggested.  I used MobX as my state management lib and marked my routes as an observable.  I change the routes, and my AppContainer refreshes.  New routes can be dynamically added and removed at will.  Thanks

Comment: You should post this as an answer and accept it so others can see that your problem was solved, especially if you solved it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I am manually loading pre-built bundles that look very similar to the Angular2 modules, where they are basically a self contained mini SPA.  The routes in those bundles are not known up front and I needed a way to add them into the main route table.

I am using MobX as my state management scheme.
The solution for me was to have a React.Component be an observer to the route table.

```
@observer
class AppRouterContainer extends React.Component {
  render() {
        const {routes} = this.props;
        return ( 
      <HashRouter>
        {/* kick it all off with the root route */}
        {renderRoutes(routes)}
      </HashRouter>
    )
    }
}
```

I then have a MobX store that manages the route table and marks the routes as observable.

```
class RouterConfigStore {
    @mobx.observable routes = [{}];
}
```

This is how it all gets bound.

```
import routerConfigStore from './stores/router-config-store';
ReactDOM.render((  
    <div>
    <DevTool />
    <AppRouterContainer routes={routerConfigStore.routes}></AppRouterContainer>

  </div>
)
, document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

So basically now I can interact with the routerConfigStore and change the route table at will.